# How to get the most recent row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a messaging system.

```
threads
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| PK | TEXT  |
+----+-------+

messages
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| id |   from_id    |   thread_id    |   sent    |   parent    | message |
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| PK | FK(users.id) | FK(threads.id) | TIMESTAMP | messages.id | TEXT    |
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+---------+

recipients
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------+
| id |     msg_id      |    to_id     | status |
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------+
| PK | FK(messages.id) | FK(users.id) | ENUM   |
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------+

users
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
| PK | VARCHAR |
+----+---------+
```

Essentially, it's a messaging system in which:

- a message thread can have multiple recipients (recipients table)
- each message thread has a title (threads.title)
- each user has his own status (read, hidden, unread) for each message (recipients.status)
- each message can be replied to (messages.parent points back to another messages.id)

So hopefully my schema is correct.

I wish to get a list of all threads, which shows the most recent message inside the thread, and the author of that message:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+---------------+-------------------+
| users.id | users.name | thread.id | thread.title | messages.message | messages.sent | recipients.status |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

The issue is getting the most recent message as part of the query. Given that recipients.status = 1 means unread.. Ignoring users for now (that'd be a relatively simple join onto the rest of the tables...), also assuming we want user 1's threads:

```
SELECT threads.id, title, message, sent, recipients.status
FROM recipients
JOIN messages
ON messages.id=recipients.msg_id
JOIN threads ON threads.id=messages.thread_id
WHERE recipients.to_id=1
AND recipients.status=1
```

This gets me all messages in all threads that the user is participating in. However, I only need the most recent, and that is where I am stuck.

One solution which I am very not fond of (are there any reasons NOT to do this?)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT threads.id, title, message, sent, recipients.status
    FROM recipients
    JOIN messages
    ON messages.id=recipients.msg_id
    JOIN threads ON threads.id=messages.thread_id
    WHERE recipients.to_id=1
    AND recipients.status=1
    ORDER BY sent DESC
) a
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Can you do an order by desc on the message.id to get get the last newest id created by that user?

Comment: need to add max(sent) to the column list and group by other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it with this:

```
SELECT threads.id AS thread_id, threads.title, users.id AS user_id, users.name, m1.message, m1.sent
FROM messages m1
LEFT JOIN messages m2
ON m1.thread_id = m2.thread_id AND m1.sent < m2.sent
JOIN recipients
ON recipients.status=1
AND recipients.msg_id=m1.id
AND recipients.to_id=1
JOIN threads
ON threads.id=m1.thread_id
JOIN users
ON m1.from_id=users.id
WHERE m2.sent IS NULL
```

The relevant parts to the problem would be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM messages m1
LEFT JOIN messages m2
ON m1.thread_id = m2.thread_id AND m1.sent < m2.sent
WHERE m2.sent IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

> One solution which I am very not fond of (are there any reasons NOT to
>   do this?)

Your query will not necessarily select the row with the latest `sent` value for each thread. Even though your inner query orders by `sent DESC`, mysql is free to choose any value from each group:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values within each group the server chooses.

I recommend using variables to emulate `row_number()` to number messages within a thread in order of when they were sent (i.e. most recent sent message within a thread will be #1, 2nd most recent #2, etc) and then to only keep #1 messages.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT threads.id, title, message, sent, recipients.status,
    @rowNumber := IF(@prevId = threads.id,@rowNumber+1,1) rowNumber,
    @prevId := threads.id
    FROM recipients
    JOIN messages
    ON messages.id=recipients.msg_id
    JOIN threads ON threads.id=messages.thread_id
    WHERE recipients.to_id=1
    AND recipients.status=1
    ORDER BY threads.id, sent DESC
) t1 WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

**Edit**

Another way using `not exists` to only select messages where a more recent message in the same thread does not exist.

```
SELECT threads.id, title, message, sent, recipients.status
FROM recipients
JOIN messages
ON messages.id=recipients.msg_id
JOIN threads ON threads.id=messages.thread_id
WHERE recipients.to_id=1
AND recipients.status=1
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM threads t2
    WHERE t2.id = threads.id
    AND t2.sent > threads.sent
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I had always believed GROUP BY would choose the first row that matches the GROUP function (and it DOES appear what my server does in this particular case), but I know now not to rely on it. This is very good information to know!

Answer (score 0):

Same answer than SoftwareCarpente, just add an Order By desc on the message id (or the timestamp) and add a LIMIT 1 if you only need the 1st row.

Comment: This will not work, will it? I need ALL threads with their respective most recent message.

Comment: Then join the threads, and order by thread id and message id.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent message id from each thread can be gotten thusly.

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS most_recent_message_id,
       thread_id
  FROM messages
 GROUP BY thread_id
```

Do you want this to be efficient? In that case create a compound index on `(thread_id, id)`.

If you want a list of threads in which a given user (let's say user 42) is participating either as originator or recipient, you need to use a UNION operator

SELECT DISTINCT thread_id
     FROM messages
    WHERE user_id = 42
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT thread_id
     FROM recipients
     JOIN messages ON recipients.msg_id = messages.id
    WHERE recipients.to_id = 42

This gets you the threads in which a user is participating.

So, if you want the ids of the most recent messages in which your user is participating (either as originator or recipient) you join those two subqueries

```
SELECT most_recent_message_id
  FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS most_recent_message_id,
               thread_id
          FROM messages
         GROUP BY thread_id
       ) AS a
  JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT thread_id
         FROM messages
        WHERE user_id = 42
       UNION
       SELECT DISTINCT thread_id
         FROM recipients
         JOIN messages ON recipients.msg_id = messages.id
        WHERE recipients.to_id = 42
       ) AS b ON a.thread_id = b.thread_id
```

See how this goes? You use the aggregation `MAX()` and set-construction (`DISTINCT`, `UNION`) features of SQL to construct the lists of relevant items, then you JOIN to get the list you want.

I assume that once you have an appropriate list of messages, you can go get the content you need with another join or two.